# ASp.net MVC with Report Viewer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, reportviewer

How can i set up rdlc (report file,with Reprort viewer) on ASP.net MVC 2.0?

I have created rdlc file..

And when i drag report viewer in the mvc page it shuffles and it doest not fit like what weve done in winform application / webform . Even you create new My First MVC application Report viewer also distorted.I place the report viewer in a table and not still fit.

I tried to create a webform that excluded in my mvc masterpage and the report viewer fits well.

Whats should i do?

Thanks in regards..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I posted the code at my blog. Let me know if this is helpful.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sajoshi/archive/2010/06/16/asp-net-mvc-handling-ssrs-reports-with-reportviewer-part-i.aspx

Comment: Ok so it is still the way we do it in a typical asp.net webform application...we just need to pass the parameters from our view to the report.aspx..I am using rdlc/local report because i am having a problem in our report server...

Comment: Yes. It is still the old ASP.NET way.To add to your point - Local reports will still work with this approach. all reports care about is the Datasource. In case of report server, you just call a URL.. In case of a local report, you first pass the data source then bind to report.

Comment: @sajoshi  I cannot access your blog post on msdn.

Answer (score 0):

The ReportViewer component is not intended to be used with ASP.NET MVC and is unsupported. You may [checkout this example](http://mvcrdlc.codeplex.com/). You could have a standard WebForms page (not MVC) generate the report and then include it either with iframe inside your MVC application or have it generate the report as PDF which then could be embedded.

Comment: I already downloaded it last few days...What are the other things to be used? I have three parameters that need to pass in my report namely an id,datefrom and dateto.

Comment: For passing parameters, we used an iframe and GET parameters which we then accessed in the code behind file and passed to the reportviewer control.

Comment: is there any blog,on how to do that?